# create2 commands with an app called SERIAL

Tags: mobile-robot, irobot-create, serial

there is an app called [SERIAL,](https://www.decisivetactics.com/products/serial/) available in the app store. 
I've downloaded it on my mac and am experimenting with it, any ideas on how to send create2 OI commands using "Serial"?

so far it seems a handy app, I've bypassed all the need for other drivers. anyone else use SERIAL/something of the like?

*when the SERIAL terminal is open and the number 9 is pressed on my mac it seems to activate cleaning mode. thats all the communication I'm getting after hours of playing around in python and mac terminal.  [image]

Comment: Does serial allow you to send streams of binary data outside of the ASCII character set?  I kind of doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that what you are trying won't work.  See this other question for the difference between trying to command the Create with a terminal vs. code: [Sending commands from Ubuntu](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/8731/sending-commands-from-ubuntu).