# Irobot Create 2 Open Interface Communication

Tags: irobot-create, serial

I am able to connect the create 2 robot to my laptop with a serial cable.  I am using putty_beta terminal to run. I am not able to key in commands in the terminal. but I am able to receive information from the robot. I want to achieve two way serial connection. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Why do you think you don't have two-way serial communication? You definitely are receiving information. Try pressing control+G while in PuTTY; this will send character code 7, which should reset the robot. If the robot resets, you have two-way communication.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to send commands just using putty, because putty sends every character individually. You need to write your own code or use something  like https://github.com/xa4a/go-roomba to communicate with the roomba

Answer (score 1):

The Roomba expects binary data.  When you type in the PuTTY terminal, you are sending [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) data.  For example when you type "128" into the terminal, you are actually sending 3 bytes of data: [49 50 56].  And because many commands of the [OI Spec](http://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/create_2_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf?la=en) are outside the typeable ASCII range, using the terminal in this manner won't work.

You should use a programming language such as [C](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7158/c-and-create2), [C#](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7018/irobot-create-2-c-connection), [Python](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6831/where-can-i-get-openinterface-py), etc. to send the data packet.  There are many libraries for the Create2 freely available online.